# Rails: Me or them, files not being required in files from config/initializers/*.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having really odd behavior with Rails, and I can't seem to figure out the problem.  When I do require inside of a file in config/initializers nothing gets required...at all, here is an example:

```
From: /home/jordon/development/test1/config/initializers/test1.rb @ line 6:

   1: Dir[Test1::Application.config.root + '/lib/test1/**/*.rb'].each do |file|
   2:   # Test1::Patches::Redirecting
   3:   require file
   4: end
   5: 
 * 6: binding.pry

[1] pry(main)> Test1::Patches
               ^> NameError: uninitialized constant Test1::Patches
               ^> From (pry):1:in `<top (required)>'

[2] # The required file is from lib/test1.
[3] pry(main)> require 'rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/redirecting'
               ^> Return: true
```

Can anyone explain what is happening? Is there some kind of anti-require faerie built into Rails?  No seriously, all joking aside can anyone seriously explain why Rails is not actually allowing my files to be required and how can I convince it to require my files so that I can attempt to extend redirect_to with wrappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
require file
```

In your environment.rb, and restart your server.